# I want to convert a html code to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

can you guys help me out with a problem?

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="chatbox__body__message chatbox__body__message--left">

    <div class="chatbox_timing">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 22/11/2018</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 7:00 PM</a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg" alt="Picture">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="ul_section_full">
        <ul class="ul_msg">
            <li><strong>Person Name</strong></li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And I do have a database with date,image,name and message, but I need to convert this HTML to some JavaScript, I mean something like this

```
if(data.length) {
    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
    {
        console.log(data[x]);
        var message = document.createElement('div');
        message.setAttribute('class','chat-messages');

        message.textContent = data[x].nickname+": "+data[x].message;
        messages.appendChild(message);
        messages.insertBefore(message,messages.firstChild);
    }
}
```

But I don't really know how to convert it, to specify it's a chat box, and there will be a lot of 'boxes' can you help me out to convert that?

Comment: The simplest way would (most likely) be to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create the HTML code and then use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)  to add it to the page.

Comment: just get the element in old fashion way `var elm = document.getElementsByClassName("chatbox__body__message ");`. You can then now process the html stored in the variable. Is this what you mean?

Comment: okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've programmed your above html code into javascript for you.

```
 <script>

function scriptIt(val){
val.value=val.value.replace(/"/gi,"&#34;")
val.value=val.value.replace(/'/gi,"&#39;")
valArr=escape(val.value).split("%0D%0A")
val.value=""
for (i=0; i<valArr.length; i++){
val.value+= (i==0) ? "<script>\ninfo=" : ""
val.value+= "\"" + unescape(valArr[i])
val.value+= (i!=valArr.length-1) ? "\" + \n" : "\"\n" 
}
val.value+="\ndocument.write(info)\n<\/script>"
}

function ctrlA(el) {
with(el){
focus(); select() 
}
if(document.all){
txt=el.createTextRange()
txt.execCommand("Copy") 
window.status='Selected and copied to clipboard!'
}
else window.status='Press ctrl-c to copy the text to the clipboard'
setTimeout("window.status=''",3000)
} 

</script>
<center>
<form name="f">
<input type="button" value="HTML -> JavaScript" onclick="scriptIt(document.f.t)" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="ctrlA(document.f.t)" />
<br />
<textarea name="t" cols="75"
rows="20"></textarea>
<br />
</form>
</center>
```

Comment: Thabk you for the effort, but sad you did not not explain whats going on.

Comment: An explanation is difficult, but I have simply explained each single line in Javascript. For example, if you have a French sentence now and you want to translate it into English, you do it similar to the HTML code in the javascript.

Comment: Currently I'm unable to see the connection between this answer and the question.

Comment: Should I explain it to you more exactly?

Comment: I think OP wants a piece of JS code, that dynamically renders the above example using custom values provided in `data`. Your script on the other hand basically just wraps a *constant* piece of HTML code in a `document.write()`. Apart from that `document.write()` in most cases is considered bad practice, I don't see how the different entries in `data` are rendered here.